# Javascript If function to check for specific referring domains

Tags: javascript, url, if-statement, indexof, referrer

Trying to create an if function with an AND condition that looks for specific domains in the referrer.
Example:

if -> 
[ **(referrer contains "www.google." OR "www.bing." Or "www.yahoo." ) AND (query param X is not in the URL)** ]

do this : -----
else: do that ---

What would be the best way for accomplishing this?

Comment: The solve-it-all solution: regex

Answer (score 2):

Could use regular expressions to do it fairly easily like this:

```
if(/www\.(google|bing|yahoo)/.test(document.referrer) && 
  !/(&|\?)paramX/.test(document.referrer)){
  //do this
} else {
  //do that
}
```

Comment: Wow, I wont even post what I was working on, nice work!

Comment: Awesome! will give it a try!